# Bootstrap grid alignment of images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a Node/Express staff directory. It's all working fine so far except one single image appears out of line and I cannot figure out why this one image is not behaving like the rest. The first image in the row is higher than the rest, even though all images are the same size, and all are placed on the page with the same class. This is what the page looks like:
[image: Staff Directory]

As you can see, only the first image is falling out out alignment.
 I've attached the relevant parts of the code in hopes that someone could see something I am obviously missing.

Thanks for the help!

This is my header.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
```

This is the staff.ejs file:

```
<%include header %>

<div class = "container">

<header class = "jumbotron">
    <h1>Staff Directory</h1>
</header>

<div class = "row row-grid">
<% staff.forEach(function(staff){ %>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class = "imagewrap">
        <!--<h4><%= staff.name %></h4>-->
        <img src = "<%=staff.image%>">
        <a href = "#" class="round-button"><%=staff.initials%></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<% }); %>
</div>

</div>  




<%include footer%>
```

And this is my css:

```
/* THE CSS TO OVERLAY BUTTON ON THE BOTTOM LEFT CORNER OF IMAGE */
.imagewrap {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

.button2 {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

/* A BUNCH OF CSS TO MAKE A ROUND BUTTON*/
.round-button {
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #4679BD; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}

.round-button:hover {
    background:#30588e;
}
img {
    width:100%;

}
.row .display-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row .display-flex > [class*='col-'] {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.row.row-grid [class*="col-"] + [class*="col-"] {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it - the problem was the row-grid class. I deleted the second [class*="col-"], and the first picture fell into place. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

due to the CSS/Bootstrap Have you tried it on

```
'img-thumbnail'     //Shapes the image to a thumbnail   
'img-responsive'    //Makes an image responsive (will scale nicely to the parent element)
```

as you can use it

```
 <img src = "<%=staff.image%>" class="img-responsive">
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that didn't work. I tried to place both classes after the img tag, but neither would align the first image.

Comment: What bootstrap version you are using

Comment: I downloaded the current one from the site, so I believe it is 4.0. Since the application will run without internet connectivity, I did not use the CDN

Comment: ok, might be different version as img-responsive no longer in the 4 as it change to .img-fluid. max-width: 100%; and height: auto; 
 you can look at it https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images

Comment: Sorry, I can't be much more help. but let me know if nobody assists you, then I might help you.

Comment: Fixed it - the problem was the row-grid class. I deleted the second [class*="col-"], and the first picture fell into place. Thanks!!

Comment: Ah, no worries. glad you got fixed it